# Object Page with blocks

Tags: sapui5

I've got this ObjectPageLayout:

**request.view.xml**

```
    <ObjectPageLayout>
        <headerTitle>
            ...
        </headerTitle>
        <headerContent>
            ...
        </headerContent>

        <sections>
            <ObjectPageSection
                mode="Collapsed">
                <subSections>
                    <ObjectPageSubSection title="fooBlock">
                        <blocks>
                            <blockdetail:FormBlock columnLayout="auto" /> <!-- MY BLOCK -->
                        </blocks>
                    </ObjectPageSubSection>
                </subSections>
            </ObjectPageSection>
        </sections>
    </ObjectPageLayout>
```

**FormBlockCollapsed.view.xml** (MY BLOCK)

```
<mvc:View xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="NAMESPACE.blocks.DetailsBlockCommon">
    <FlexBox>
        <HBox>
            <VBox>
                <f:SimpleForm >
                    <f:content>
                        <CheckBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="myCheckbox" />
                    </f:content>
                </f:SimpleForm>
            </VBox>
        </HBox>
    </FlexBox>
...
</mvc:View>
```

So far, everything is fine. My Object page looks good a the checkbox is shown.

In my Controller **request.controller.js** i want to validate the checkbox in FormBlockCollapsed.view.xml

```
validateBlockForm: function(format){
    console.log( oView.byId("myCheckbox").checked() ); //oView.byId("myCheckbox") is undefined
}
```

But i've no access to my checkbox in the block.

> Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

### Further infos

**FormBlock.js**

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/uxap/BlockBase'], function (BlockBase) {
    "use strict";

    var MultiViewBlock = BlockBase.extend("NAMESPACE.blocks.FormBlock", {
        metadata: {
            views: {
                Collapsed: {
                    viewName: "NAMESPACE.blocks.FormBlockCollapsed",
                    type: "XML"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return MultiViewBlock;
}, true);
```

**DetailBlockCommon.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "NAMESPACE/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("NAMESPACE.blocks.DetailsBlockCommon", {


    });
});
```

Comment: request.controller.js is NOT the controller associated with the FormBlockCollapsed view. Either access the element through sap.ui.core or in the correct controller :)

Comment: sap.ui.getCore().byId("myCheckbox") is also undefined. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements in a section by having the block's id and element's id.

First we have to define an id for the block in the xml view:

```xml
<blocks>
        <blockdetail:FormBlock id="formBlock" columnLayout="auto" /> <!-- MY BLOCK -->
</blocks>
```

Then we generate the id of the elements like the following in the view controller. The state of the art here is to add `-Collapsed--` as part of the id that adds by SAPUI5 to sections elements.

```js
var sFieldId = this.getView().createId("formBlock") + 
                                       "-Collapsed--myCheckbox";
var oCheckbox = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sFieldId);
```

Answer (score -4):

Check if oView is defined.

you can easily get it by this.getView()

Comment: oView is defined otherwise the error would be "Cannot read property 'ById' of undefined